# Playing webview with flash without installing flash from the market

Tags: android, flash

I am trying to build an application where the webview should handle flash contents.
As most of us are aware of, Adobe has announced it will not support Flash Player browser plugin for Android 4.1 and onward.
Without installing Flash, is it possible to realize it?
I did my part of researches and came along with `Captive Runtime` where you can have the flash package inside your application, without the need to install flash.
My question is, is it possible to build an android app without using Flash Builder, and have the flash package inside?
Is Adobe Air the only solution in my case?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem...Plz help if anyone has a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adobe AIR** is the one and only **hope**. You don't need FLASH here in this context. Make sure you have the **Flash Builder 4.6** to build the application, test it with the inbuilt emulator to see how it all goes.